# Override get_object() and manually set PK

Tags: python, django

I have a `DetailView` class in which I am not passing in a pk nor a slug. Therefore, I am trying to override the `get_object(self)` and manually place the query filter item (in my case the user that is currently logged in). However, I am not having success:

```
class ViewSpecialUser(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = SpecialUser
    print(self)

    def get_object(self):

        object = super(ViewSpecialUser, self).get_object(queryset)
        object.queryset = queryset.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return object

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewSpecialUser, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just return instance of Model:

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.model.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
```

Answer (score 8):

`get_object` will be called with an optional `queryset` parameter, which you're ignoring and you're probably getting a `TypeError: get_object() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` exception. *Even* if your `get_object` is being called without the `queryset` parameter in your specific situation, you're then actually trying to *reference* that same `queryset` variable that you have never defined in the first place, so you're probably getting a `NameError: global name 'queryset' not defined` exception.

The `SingleObjectMixin`'s implementation of `get_object` [sets up a default for the `queryset` parameter](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/views/generic/detail.py#L30) if it's not provided, and you should to the same:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    ...
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    ...
```

You should then use that `queryset` (coming either as a parameter or from `self.get_queryset()`) to look up your user:

```
    return queryset.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
```

This, of course, assumes that either 1) `SpecialUser` is the user model used in your authentication in the first place, or 2) it has `pk`s in sync with whatever your actual user model is.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one